# Firebase database query not returning when offline

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to run a query on the firebase database and if the user is offline I want to display a pop up to the user prompting them to try again. However the query does not return when offline.

```
databaseRef.queryEqual(toValue: "someValue").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot) //this is never called when user is offline
}) { (error) in
    print(error)    //neither is this
}
```

What is the best strategy to run this query and detect if the user was offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the database client is not connected to its backend *and* it doesn't have any knowledge of the location in its cache, it cannot invoke your callback.

You can detect whether the Firebase client is connected to its backend by observing `.info/connected`. See the [Firebase documentation for an example of detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state).

Comment: Thanks Puf! What would you recommend as a best (safest) approach. 1) Just as in your answer, listning to wether the firebase client is connected and disallowing a query if not connected, or 2) Try the query and if the query doesn't return within X seconds then consider it failed and remove the observer?

Comment: I'd never work with time-outs unless I have a need for something time-based. That's not the case here. If the location is completely new and created in the client, consider priming the location by calling `setValue(nil)` on it. That way the client knows that there is no value and will fire. I recently answer a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430992/firebase-ondatachange-not-called-when-offline/42431732#42431732